# EAS - Update app bundle OTA when 'channel' is not specified?

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

I have the following build profile in my eas.json:

```
"build": {
   "production": {}
}
```

I have built my app using `eas build` **without specifying the 'channel'** under the 'production' profile:

`eas build -p android --profile production`

[Build details in expo dev](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSoBK.png)

As you can see in the image the 'Release Channel' is set to 'default'.

My problem is that I can't find a way to update the app bundle on the air (OTA update).

**I have tried the following but with no luck:**

1. Update the 'default' branch using:

`eas update --branch default --message "first update"`

2. Create a 'default' profile with `"channel: 'default'"`:

   "build": {
   "default": {
   "channel": "default",
   }
   }

[expo.dev](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSQaz.png)

3. Then link the channel to some other branch ('staging' in that case):

`eas channel:edit default --branch staging`

```
and then:
```

`eas update --branch staging --message "first update"`

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any solution online.

NOTE: I know I can create a new build with proper channel and continue from there but I need to update the build which is currently available at App Store and fix a bug ASAP (before the new version will be available in the store).

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. Any luck finding a solution?

Comment: @Dassy did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: I ended up creating new builds with a channel specified in the eas.json